# jQuery mobile, how to add a pin to a google map

Tags: jquery, mobile, maps

I'm using the example code from jQuery documents

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMap" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15">

    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>

    <iframe src="map.html" width="480" height="320" seamless></iframe>

</div>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 51.520838, -0.140261 );
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "map_canvas" ), myOptions );
        }
    </script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <style>
        html {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #map_canvas { 
            height: 100%;
        }    
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this opens up Google maps in a popup windows in the screen.

But how can I make this work with a pin dropped at a specific location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will add a marker to your map in the position -25.363882, 131.044922:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 51.520838, -0.140261 );
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "map_canvas" ), myOptions );
    var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerLatlng,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

I really encourage you to read the [Google Maps API Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#AddingOverlays)